# Can't assign input value to a variable in JQuery - var newserial = $("#myserial").val();

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
Model #     : <input type="text" name="model" id="newmodel" value="" >
Serial #    : <input type="text" name="fserial" value="" class="serialClass" id="myserial">

in script I have: enter code here
```

```js
<script>
       //Here I can't get the value of serial# with the id="myserial"
       var newserial = $("#myserial").val();
    
    
     $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#myserial').change(function(){
            //this is a test alert, (OUTPUT = "seial number: undefined variable"), which means that 
      alert("serial number: "+ newserial);
       
               $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'toshGet.php',
                    //upon success, pass newserial
        data: {keyword: newserial},
        success: function(msg){
         $('#txtHint').html(msg);
        }
       });//ajax()
      });//change()
     });//document.ready()   
    </script>
```

### I know this is really strange but can't get assigned the text input's value to the variable "newserial". Here is so far a piece of the code:

Comment: It seems that initial value of input is empty, `value=""`.

Comment: I don't think there is anything strange in it... `var newserial = $("#myserial").val();` should in the change event handler

Comment: Move `var newserial = $("#myserial").val();` in `$( document ).ready()`, also - where is `model` defined?

Comment: do you want serial value after change or before change/

Comment: you are having `model` variable in alert while you are populating newserial variable ,hence model is undefined

Answer (score -2):

The problem in your case is that you are assigning element with id `'myserial'` to a variable when it is not rendered properly inside DOM.

Instead of assigning `var newserial = $("#myserial").val();` outside `document.ready()` try this:

```
var newserial;

$(document).ready(function(){
  newserial = $("#myserial").val();
  ....
});
```

**Or** (if you want updated value of `'#myserial'` then)

Use `var newserial = $("#myserial").val();` or `var newserial = $(this).val();` inside change event handler itself.

**Or**

Just assign value directly without taking any extra variable in ajax call as shown :

```
data: { keyword: $("#myserial").val() }, //or $(this).val()
```

**Side Note :-** Your `alert("serial number: "+model);` is absolutely wrong because there is no variable with name model in your code.

Comment: Or event better: data: {keyword: $('#myserial').val()},

Comment: even then you will not get the updated value as it is not read after the change event

Comment: He is using model variable to alert have you seen that?